# Div takes up entire width in IE 7 (has right floated block-element children)

Tags: css

I have a few right floated block elements ( anchor elements with display:block because I need to set heights on them) inside a parent div.

There is other markup around the parent div (The parent div is supposed to act as a toolbar with the links as buttons)

This arrangement works fine in all browsers except IE7 where, instead of sizing the parent div to it's parent, the div takes up the entire width on the page.

Is this a known bug on IE7 ? I have tried applying clearfix on the parent div but that doesn't seem to do the job.

I have pasted the markup and CSS here : http://pastebin.com/m37ffbdf9

Comment: Here is the markup and the CSS :

http://pastebin.com/m37ffbdf9

Answer (score 0):

The display style property is ignored for elements which have float set to a value other than none.
Dit you try setting position:relative on the parent div?

Comment: Yes, I tried that (the parent div is absolutely positioned) but that doesn't work. Tried removing padding / margins from the block elements as well. no go.